# Speckie issue for multiple ckeditor instances in IE11

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

I have 4 instances of **ckeditor(4.4)** On a single page. We are not using wsc plugin for spellcheck since our project needs Speckie(I am using Speckie7).

On clicking inside THE 1st ckeditor textbox , misspelled words are getting underlined properly. but if click in other instances, only newly typed misspelled words are getting underlined,but not previously saved misspelled words :(.

It used to work with IE9 but since we upgraded to IE11 (again project Requirements), it is showing this behavior.  I cannot add code here due to some restrictions.

Really appreciate your help if someone else has also faced similar issue.

**Update** : I managed to get it work with Speckie 6.

Comment: There is no restriction about code in your post.  You need to paste it in as part of your post (NOT links).  Just post the minimum required to produce the problem.

Comment: I cannot add the code since we have done many configurations to ckeditor and it is spread across the application.Also I am quite new to this I dont know how to reproduce it.But it is working fine with IE9 but only in IE11 it is doing spellcheck in first textarea only. Thanks in advance.